# Why the limit of only 1 post every 40 minutes on meta sites for trusted Stack Exchange contributors?

Tags: discussion, support, per-site-meta, rate-limiting

People like myself are Stack Exchange trusted users with thousands of reputation points and hundreds of badges.  In other words, we've proven ourselves as people who are assets to Stack Exchange and are a key component in making it so profitable.

As such, I was surprised when I posted [a question](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2087/shall-we-make-some-questions-regarding-icon) on the [User Experience meta](http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com) site, and then shortly afterwards tried to [report a bug](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2089/https-broken-for-this-stackexchange-meta-site) on that same meta site, but was blocked with a message in red stating I had to wait 40 minutes before posting again.

Why is this limit present for trusted Stack Exchange contributors, and can it be changed?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: By the way, finding the intended behavior will let us know it is a bug (or ["bugged"](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/325985/is-the-use-of-the-term-bugged-to-refer-to-software-bugs-in-english-a-worldwide)... LOL) or a feature.  If it's a bug, perhaps it can get fixed.  If it's a feature, perhaps we can work to improve the feature! :-)

Comment: You have less than 125 rep on User Experience.

Comment: @RobertLongson Yes, which is a bit ironic given my area of professional expertise.  I just gave it a test, and son of a gun, you're right.  It's  surprising that I've never run into this issue before.

Comment: BTW, I found the text that confused me.  The [*Complete Rate Limiting Guide*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) states "Users < 125 rep, 40 minutes, network-wide".  The words "network-wide" apparently applies to the limitation, not the reputation.  Maybe we can work on the wording over at UX. ;-)

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322157/arent-new-users-throttled-asking-questions-anymore/322265#322265) answer on MSO

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Robert Longson provided documentation revealing that this limitation is intentional and not a bug.  Many thanks to Mr. Longson!

So let's look at this limitation and decide if we still want it.

For users who are new to Stack Exchange, it makes sense to impose reasonable limits.  After all, we don't want spam, and we don't want community moderators to be overtaxed having to deal with a bunch of off topic questions.

But for dedicated Stack Exchange contributors, what's the harm in allowing us to ask a question on History SE and then an unrelated one 10 minutes later on Mythology SE?

Actually, let's look at it the other way.  What's the benefit?  The benefit is more quality questions from experienced Stack Exchange contributors.  That's a win-win for Stack Exchange and the contributors!

Comment: AFAIK, the only place rep crosses between sites is in Chat... You have to earn your privs on **every** site if you want to use that site's full features... you're not a trusted user there if you don't have rep on that site.  You're essentially asking for a change to the entire concept of this network.

Comment: "Still" want it? Since it was added in the last few months, I'd say so!

Comment: @Catija That's not true: if you have 200 rep on one site, then you get a 100 rep bonus on every site. This bonus overcomes most newcomer restrictions, including some of the rate limits, but for some reason not this particular rate limit.

Comment: @Gilles  that rep has limitations. It's not real rep. And it's not carte blanche... 100 rep does very little in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Why not? Because you don't know their on topic off topic rules, you've not searched for duplicates (and won't have experience of previous questions)...

Comment: @Tim Huh?  So they shouldn't be allowed to post at all?  This about allowing experienced and trusted SE contributors to post on one SE site, and then still allowing them to post on a completely different SE site within 40 minutes (when they have under 125 rep on each of those sites).  I think perhaps you misread the answer.

Comment: The main reason there are network limits is to prevent spammers creating multiple accounts and then posting cross-network spam. A few spammers have been patient enough to get rep on one site (probably via voting rings) so they get a network bonus and then spam all sites.

Comment: @RobertLongson That makes good sense.  Consequently, the need to require an appropriately high level of trust.  Something like 2000 total combined reputation points on all SE sites on which the user has at least 250 points.  That will separate the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard I read it. My point is if you are posting within 40 minutes you've not researched enough.

Comment: @Tim SE is designed better than to require 40 minutes to read what is on topic, get a quick sense of the site, and perform a search to make sure the same question has not already been asked.  If SE really wanted experienced contributors (or anyone for that matter) to spend 40 minutes on a site before posting, then they would prevent people from posting for the first 40 minutes after signing up for any SE site.

Comment: Some frequent contributors go online to perform research, write their thorough questions offline, and then want to re-connect to the internet to post different questions on a few SE sites at once.  What I do now, is when I can't post a question due to the 40 minute restriction, I just post my questions on sites outside of the StackExchange network instead of on the StackExchange network.